# Asp.Net web app read query performance

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, ado.net

using EntityFramework 5 (POCO),  SQL2012, ASP.NET-MVC4.

My problem is that, my app runs slow, the reason is that the technology stack I mentioned above uses the same connection for different queries running on the same server.

Lets say we have two different queries, one runs slow (up to a minute), another one quite fast 1,2 secs. Even on the test server when there is only one user and that is me, if I open two different browser windows(sharing same session),and execute the long query first and then the quick query next at the same time, and when I query the running sessions on the sql server for the active ones I only see one session, and as a result, the quick query also gets stuck waiting on the slow query.
I tried couple of things and got random results:
I disabled pooling on the connections string;

```
Pooling=False;
```

Sometimes it ran those queries in two different sessions, sometimes in one. I set the min pool size to 10, I think until hitting the min pool size, it was okay, then it started using the same db session.

Another thing is that MARS was enabled by default;
And I tried removing that, (I do not know the full impact of this atm, I have not tested everything, so actually I intend to leave this enabled.) and I again got random results.

I used two different browsers, so 2 different IIS Sessions, and got better results. It opened up two db sessions for each query.

We use MSDTC so all the transactions run in a transaction context and this leaves all open connections in Serializable setting, as a result we had to run read queryies also in Transaction Scopes and opted for Read Uncommitted isolation level in that one.

So having quite a capable SQL Server, how can I prevent ASP.Net/ADO.Net/EF5 from using a connection that still has a query running on the server.

PS: I instantiate DbContext by passing in a connection string to the DbContexts's constructor.
The queries running above are on two different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to fix the problem.

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class SomeController: Controller
```

If you set the session state to readonly, Asp.Net MVC lets you have multiple queries running at the same time.